# Error loading jupyter notebook - Unreadable Notebook - OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, compiler-errors, loading

I cannot open a jupyter notebook.
When I try to open it, I get the error message

```
ERROR LOADING NOTEBOOK
Unreadable Notebook: path\notebookname.ipynb
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
```

I tried to open other notebooks in the same directory and I can do that.

Any idea how to help me???